# Is there a canonical way to add build scripts to a Go project?

Tags: go, build, organization, build-script

Coming from the Node.js world, whenever you need a script (such as a build script there), a very common way of handling this is by adding it to the `scripts` block in the `package.json` file, so that you can the script by calling `npm run <scriptname>`. In other words, Node.js (respectively npm) has a built-in way to deal with (simple) scripts.

Does an equivalent to this exist in the Go world?

To put it differently: Suppose I have some commands such as doing a build, cleaning the build directory, creating a new version, and so on, is there a better way to do this than by adding a bunch of (platform-dependant) Bash script files?

In case there isn't – is there at least a common way of where to put these scripts? Or is this all left to the developer?

Comment: we found `Makefile`s are easy to use with Go and almost platform-independent

Comment: On Windows we use batch files for this task, setting environment variables like GOOS for the target OS then on successful compile we also start the project. We have separate batch file for debug build, turning off optimizations and also have some for other platforms, so we can build executables for Linux on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Makefile`

this one is what I use sometimes:

```
BINARY_NAME=main
 
build:
    go mod tidy
    go build -o ${BINARY_NAME} main.go
 
clean:
    go clean
    rm ${BINARY_NAME}
```